# read lock yealds when MongoDB predicts data not in memory?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, locking

> Changed in version 2.2: The use of yielding expanded greatly in MongoDB 2.2. Including the “yield for page fault.” MongoDB tracks the contents of memory and predicts whether data is available before performing a read. If MongoDB predicts that the data is not in memory a read operation yields its lock while MongoDB loads the data to memory. Once data is available in memory, the read will reacquire the lock to complete the operation.

Taken from ["Does a read or write operation ever yield the lock?"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#faq-concurrency-locking)

**Imagine that a write operation acquires the lock. How can a write be performed (change a certain collection) while MongoDB reading the data from the same collection. What happens if part of the read collection was not changed by the write and part of it was changed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Imagine that a write operation acquires the lock. How can a write be performed (change a certain collection) while MongoDB reading the data from the same collection.

It cannot, MongoDB has a writer greedy read/write database level lock ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use ).

While a single document write is occuring MongoDB is blocked from reading on a database wide level.

> What happens if part of the read collection was not changed by the write and part of it was changed?

MongoDB is transactional to a single document which means that if a part of a large multi update fails then it fails, there is no rollback or atomicity or transaction for the life time of the multi update.

Comment: I know that the write is exclusive, and I know that operations are atomic only on a single document. But it states in the documentation that in order to improve performance they made the read lock yield when MongoDB sees that the data is not yet in memory (only on disk). Think about what happens when a write operation acquires the lock. Does it update data directly on disk? Or does it wait for the data to be in memory and update it there (then why yielding the lock in first place)? This is the confusing part "yields its lock while MongoDB loads the data to memory".

Comment: @despot MongoDB will load the document into memory and then push it back to disk, aka it has to read before it can write

Comment: ok that is logical then. The collection goes to memory, writer picksup write lock, update them in memory, update them on disk, writer gives up lock and reader can read the updated collection. It seems like this is done to give priority to writes. Right?

Comment: @despot indeed everyting is write priority though writes do have some rules to say, "Look there are quite a few reads waiting": http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/